# No ResultSet from stored procedure with temporary table with JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I have a stored procedure which creates a temp table and populates the temp table. After populating it, it returns the rows inside the table with (`SELECT`).

When running it from MySQL workbench works tremendously but in JAVA with JDBC, the ResultSet is empty. I have gone through some posts which say that we should not use `PreparedStatment` but even `Statement` doesn't work.

For test, I divided the job in stored procedure. Now I call:

```
CallableStatement ps = connection.prepareCall("{CALL myProcedure(?)}");
ps.setString(1, "value");
ps.execute();
```

which creates the temp table and populates it. Thereafter with same connection I try to do

```
Statement st = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tmp_table");
```

Still ResultSet is empty. What can I do? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is your connection setting? may be they are not committed?

Comment: My guess, since it works on the workbench would be to do with transactions, try adding a transaction to your java code. May be temp table is discarded once the transaction ends and your codes does not use a transaction when invoking the stored procedure.

Comment: It´s a connection-pool in tomcat resources with auto-commit=true; I tried transcation and commit in MySQL procedure. but I can try in java too.

Comment: once the procedure is executed from java, check in the database that your temp table is created, if its created then its the problem with your select statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you folks for help! 
I found the error. The error was in code.

I send a parameter when calling procedure. For testing purposes I did

```
SET @param = "value";
```

Later on, I removed it but I forgot to remove it when inserting data into temporary table which used that `@param`. MySQL somehow could see that `@param` and `IN param` is same because of name but JDBC could not see that and Therefore, it was not returning any data.